# How to handle API that returns on main thread in NSOperation

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, core-data, concurrency, nsoperation

I need to take a snapshot of a mapView with the MKMapSnapshotter API and do some manipulation of the image it returns, as well as fetching and writing to core data. As it's all one piece of work, I wrapped it up in an NSOperation object which is executed on a background NSOperationQueue.

The MKSnapshotter api either runs the completion block on the main thread:

`- (void)startWithCompletionHandler:(MKMapSnapshotCompletionHandler)completionHandler`

or it lets you specify a dispatch queue to use:

`- (void)startWithQueue:(dispatch_queue_t)queue completionHandler:(MKMapSnapshotCompletionHandler)completionHandler`

...so when it returns in `setSnapshot:` I'm always on a different thread than I should be, which potentially borks my core data managed object context. Is there a way to refer to the thread I called the snapshotter from? Or do I need to rethink my design here?

```
- (instancetype) initWithManagedObject:(NSManagedObject *)managedObject {

    // store object id for later use
    _objectID = managedObject.objectID;
    _mainThreadContext = managedObject.managedObjectContext;
    ...
}

- (void)start {
    // do stuff with core data on the background moc
    self.backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [self.backgroundContext setParentContext:self.parentContext];
    NSError *objectIDRetrievalError = nil;
    self.objectInBackgroundContext = [self.backgroundContext existingObjectWithID:self.objectID error:&objectIDRetrievalError];
    ...

    // take the map snapshot
    ...
    [snapshotter startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
        ...
        self.snapshot = snapshot;
    }];
}
- (void)setSnapshot:(MKMapSnapshot *)snapshot {     
    // HELP, I'm on the wrong thread! 

    // do some expensive image stuff
    ...
    // do some more stuff with core data on the background moc
    [self.objectInBackgroundContext doStuff];
    ...
    [self.backgroundContext save:&error];
    ...
    [self finish];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are executing the `NSOperation` *concurrently*, as your code indicates, you basically have no control which thread is used to execute the operation's `start` method.

This complicates the latter.

Thus, I would suggest to create your *backgroundContext* using a `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` concurrency type, like so:

```
self.backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
```

(see [NSManagedObjectContext: Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001182-SW39)).

This enables you to execute any code within the managed object context's appropriate "execution context":

#### Invoking it asynchronously:

```
[self.backgroundContext performBlock: ^{
    // executing on the background context's private queue
    ...
}];
```

#### Invoking it synchronously:

```
[self.backgroundContext performBlockAndWait: ^{
    // executing on the background context's private queue
    ...
}];
```

Then, in your `start` method you invoke the "snap shotter" as follows:

```
...
[snapshotter startWithQueue:dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0) 
          completionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
    [self.backgroundContext performBlock:^{
        // executing on the background context's private queue
        ...
        self.snapshot = snapshot;

        // here you likely need to orderly "terminate" the operation queue:
        dispatch_async(_syncQueue, ^{
            // set operation result:
            if (error) { ... }
            [self terminate];
        }
    }];
}];
```

#### Side note:

The implementation of `terminate` may look as follows:

```
- (void) terminate {
    self.isExecuting = NO;
    self.isFinished = YES;
    completion_block_t completionHandler = _completionHandler;
    _completionHandler = nil;
    id result = _result;
    _self = nil;
    if (completionHandler) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
            completionHandler(result);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to call `setSnapshot` on main thread you can accomplish this by submitting operation to queue associated with main thread: `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]`

```
NSOperation *op = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{self.snapshot = snapshot;}];
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:op]
```

Or less verbose version with `GCD`

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.snapshot = snapshot;
});
```

---

**Update v2**

You may find helpful coredata's builtin concurrency support. You may start from [Concurrency Support for Managed Object Contexts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/index.html)

```
- (void)start {
    // do stuff with core data on the background moc
    self.backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [self.backgroundContext setParentContext:self.parentContext];
    __block NSError *objectIDRetrievalError = nil;
    [self.backgroundContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        self.objectInBackgroundContext = [self.backgroundContext existingObjectWithID:self.objectID error:&objectIDRetrievalError];
    }];
    ...

    // take the map snapshot
    ...
    [snapshotter startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
        ...
        self.snapshot = snapshot;
    }];
}
- (void)setSnapshot:(MKMapSnapshot *)snapshot {     
    // HELP, I'm on the wrong thread! 

    // do some expensive image stuff
    ...
    [self.backgroundContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        // do some more stuff with core data on the background moc
        [self.objectInBackgroundContext doStuff];
        ...
        [self.backgroundContext save:&error];
    }];
    ...
    [self finish];
}
```

**Update v3**

As @CouchDeveloper pointed out current operation implementation is not quite correct. According to [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/concurrencyprogrammingguide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW1) and [`NSOperation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperation/start) reference the `start` method should

1. check whether the operation was cancelled
2. establish execution environment for the task (basically create the thread or queue)
3. if `main` implemenhted

   1. call `main` method on context from (2)
   2. else run operation itself inside `start` on context from (2)

Then, combining all the stuff:

```
- (void)start {
    // Always check for cancellation before launching the task.
    if ([self isCancelled])
    {
        // Must move the operation to the finished state if it is canceled.
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        finished = YES;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        return;
    }
    // If the operation is not canceled, begin executing the task.
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    // Run main in concurrent queue
    self.dispatchQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(self.dispatchQueue, ^{
        [self main]
    });
    executing = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
}

- (void)main {
    // it runs inside self.dispatchQueue queue
    // create moc with its own private queue
    self.backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [self.backgroundContext setParentContext:self.parentContext];
    __block NSError *objectIDRetrievalError = nil;
    [self.backgroundContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        self.objectInBackgroundContext = [self.backgroundContext existingObjectWithID:self.objectID error:&objectIDRetrievalError];

    }];
    ...
    // take the map snapshot
    ...
    [snapshotter startWithQueue:self.dispatchQueue // make the completion handler run in self.dispatchQueue
              completionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
                  ...
                  self.snapshot = snapshot;
              }];
}
- (void)setSnapshot:(MKMapSnapshot *)snapshot {
    // will be performed in self.dispatchQueue too
    // do some more stuff with core data on the background moc
    [self.backgroundContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        [self.objectInBackgroundContext doStuff];
        ...
        [self.backgroundContext save:&error];

    }];
    ...
    [self finish];
}
```

Comment: Calling `setSnapshot:` on the main thread isn't the problem - putting it in the completion handler of  `snapshotter startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error)` gets me exactly that. My issue is that I want to effectively return to the thread where I called that method from...

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. So do you want to call `setSnapshot` on the thread where `start` called (== you want to call `setSnapshot` on core data's background thread)? Could you please add core data code to the question?

Comment: Yes, exactly - basically I set up a background moc for the core data when the `NSOperation` is initialized which I'd like to continue to use when the `snapshotter` completion returns.

Comment: This is conceptually _precisely_ what I'd like to do, but I don't think it's going to work: as per @CouchDeveloper 's answer, running an NSOperation concurrently (as I believe I have to do if using async API in the middle of it) means you've relinquished control over  what threads it uses. So there's no guarantee that the current thread will exist when the snapshotter returns. Also, `dispatch_get_current_queue()` seems to be deprecated in iOS7.

Comment: Then I believe the best option is to use `moc` private queues. You may find details in my `update v2`.

Comment: @MaxK You should read the documentation for `dispatch_get_current_queue()` more carefully. Especially in your "Update" scenario dispatch_get_current_queue() would NOT do what you expect, and this solution becomes incorrect.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper, yes, you're right, my `update` contains incorrect solution. I am sorry. Will update my answer.

Comment: @MaxK Your welcome ;)  Also, in your second Update, note that the `start` method shall _asynchronously_ execute the task - as this is a requirement of a NSOperation subclass.

Comment: @MaxK yep I left a lot of the operation admin stuff out of start/finish methods, but thanks for the reminder! My understanding of `dispatch_get_global_queue` is that it'll get you an async queue, but there's no guarantee that you'll run code on the same thread (since the docs say that if you give it various blocks to run, it may run them concurrently). So I think I still need a private MOC context...?

Comment: @zoë, you are right, using the same concurrent queue will not guarantee that the thread will be the same. It seems MOC private queues is the best way. I updated my answer again (update 3).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dispatch semaphore to wait for the completion handler to run and then assign your `snapshot` property after it has finished, in the original context. It's not great to block the thread in an operation, but given the constraints of the API, it may be the best choice.

```
- (void)start {
    // do stuff with core data on the background moc
    self.backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [self.backgroundContext setParentContext:self.parentContext];
    NSError *objectIDRetrievalError = nil;
    self.objectInBackgroundContext = [self.backgroundContext existingObjectWithID:self.objectID error:&objectIDRetrievalError];
    ...

    // take the map snapshot
    ...
    dispatch_semaphore_t sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    __block MKMapSnapshot *result;
    [snapshotter startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
        ...
        result = snapshot;
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
    }];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    self.snapshot = result;
}
```

Comment: yeh it's quite a blunt instrument but those can be useful! Plus, it's not really a time-sensitive operation so this approach is definitely feasible. I'm going to try the PrivateQueueConcurrency approach suggested by @CouchDeveloper but am definitely keeping this in my back pocket...